# pandas dataframe Shape of passed values is (5, 1), indices imply (5, 2)

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I see several similar questions but they have not solved my problem.

Short version:
If I create a list of tuples to use as input for a dataframe, all works as intended.
If the list of tuples comes as a result of a SQL query, I get the error mentioned in the topic name. The two lists of tuples look identical to me (I made the first list by copying from the second list so they should be the same), but not to pandas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Long version:
If I do this:

```
query_results = [('Pick_Task', 'task_internal_id'), ('Pick_Task', 'task_id'), ('Pick_Task', 'date_created'),
        ('Pick_Task', 'plan'), ('Pick_Task', 'employee_actual')]

df = pd.DataFrame(query_results, columns=['Table Name','Column Name'])
print(df)
```

I get this (which is what I would expect):

```
Table Name       Column Name
0  Pick_Task  task_internal_id
1  Pick_Task           task_id
2  Pick_Task      date_created
3  Pick_Task              plan
4  Pick_Task   employee_actual
```

If I do this:

```
query = """SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
        FROM Analyst.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Pick_Task'
        """
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query)
    query_results = cursor.fetchall()

print(query_results)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(query_results, columns = ['Table Name', 'Column Name'])
```

I get this (which is what I would expect):

```
[('Pick_Task', 'task_internal_id'), ('Pick_Task', 'task_id'), ('Pick_Task', 'date_created'), ('Pick_Task', 'plan'), ('Pick_Task', 'employee_actual')]
```

But I also get this (which is not what I expected and why I am here looking for help):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3200/749747456.py in <module>
      9 print(query_results)
     10 
---> 11 df = pd.DataFrame(query_results, columns = ['Table Name', 'Column Name'])

~\Miniconda3\envs\da1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    709                     )
    710                 else:
--> 711                     mgr = ndarray_to_mgr(
    712                         data,
    713                         index,

~\Miniconda3\envs\da1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in ndarray_to_mgr(values, index, columns, dtype, copy, typ)
    322     )
    323 
--> 324     _check_values_indices_shape_match(values, index, columns)
    325 
    326     if typ == "array":

~\Miniconda3\envs\da1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _check_values_indices_shape_match(values, index, columns)
    391         passed = values.shape
    392         implied = (len(index), len(columns))
--> 393         raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
    394 
    395 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 1), indices imply (5, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got similar problem, trying to create a DataFrame from list:

```
dt = ['a','b','c']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dt, columns=['1','2','3'])
```

Solved by passing the 'data' argument as list of lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[dt], columns=['1','2','3'])
```

So you should try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([query_results], columns = ['Table Name', 'Column Name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found that sometimes `df= pd.DataFrame([list(i) for i in query_results])` is needed.

Sometimes it works with just `df= pd.DataFrame(query_results)` due to the format of return, but when it doesn't, that list comprehension fixes it.

Doing just `list(query_results)` or `[query_results]` as the other answer suggests was not enough of a fix for me, so wanted to share in case others see this as they are searching.

Example:

```
    cursor.execute(query)
    query_results = cursor.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame([list(i) for i in query_results ], 
        columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])
    cursor.close()
    con.close()
```